# Batch file: moving specific files from subfolders to a destination folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I'm new to writing code / commands, and I was hoping for some assistance.

I need to search and copy specific files within a folder **and** its subfolders. 
I have the following script (that I use when all of the files are in one source folder):

```
@echo off
set src_folder=C:\Users\macca\Downloads
set dst_folder=C:\Users\macca\Downloads\Testing
set file_list=C:\Users\macca\Downloads\photo_test.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
xcopy "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
)

pause
```

I've tried to google this, and search on stack overflow, but I'm not finding anything (I suspect that I am using the wrong terminology) .

Comment: What's the current behaviour and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Assuming file_list contains just file names without a path you'll need another stacked `for /r` loop to search file names, what should happen if the there already is the same file name present in dst_folder ?